# Can't backfill array to larger than 1500000 elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongodb document named collection:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('53e9dd54c784717558c46997'),
    bloks: [ /* subdocument array */ ],
    sections: [ /* subdocument array */ ],
    chapters: [ /* subdocument array */ ]
}
```

and each of the subdocuments have `id` and `state` fields as strings among some other fields.

When using mongoose, I can update the `bloks` and return the collection using:

```
update = { bloks: [ /*some changed array*/ ] };

Collection.findByIdAndUpdate(collection._id, update, function (err, collection) {
    if (err) {
        // return an error
    } else {
       // return the collection
    }
});
```

But when I try to update also a specific section and chapter state in the other arrays:

```
update = { 
    bloks: [ /*some changed array*/ ],
    'sections.140439739188823467.state': 'some state',
    'chapters.1404397391757313579.state': 'some state'
};
```

I get an error:

```
Can't backfill array to larger than 1500000 elements
```

How can I update the collection document with the bloks, sections and chapters data and have it's current value?

Please note, I'm using `.findByIdAndUpdate()` because it is more efficient and I had problems making the `.update()` method do the actual save.

Comment: Do you really have `140439739188823467` elements in your array?

Comment: It is not an element, it is the ID of the subdocument, which is why I don't know how to reference it

Comment: Well, thanks for the question, I might try finding the index first :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Leonid Beschastny comment in the question, I figured out that I was using the subdocuments IDs as indices in the arrays, so I modifed the code to figure out the correct ones.

```
    sindex = _.findIndex(collection.sections, function (section) {
        return sid === section.id;
    });

    if (-1 < sindex) {
        update['sections.' + sindex + '.state'] = 'state';
    }



    hindex = _.findIndex(collection.chapters, function (chapter) {
        return hid === chapter.id;
    });
    if (-1 < hindex) {
        update['chapters.' + hindex + '.state'] = 'state';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way to update sub-document's field by its id, using [positional operator `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/):

```js
db.collection.update({
    _id: collection._id,
    'sections.id': '140439739188823467'
}, {
    'sections.$.state': 'some state'
});
```

The only problem with this approach is that you can't update multiple sub-documents using single query. So, it'll require two requests to update both `sections` and `chapters`.

---

You should also consider using `mongoose` [Sub Docs feature](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html). The only thing you'll need to change in your existing schema is the primary id field of you sub docs, because `mongoose` always use `_id` field as a primary identifier.

It'll allow you to use [`MongooseDocumentArray::id` helper](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_documentarray_MongooseDocumentArray-id), especially designed for your case:

```
sindex = collection.sections.id(sid);
hindex = collection.sections.id(hid);
```

---

And another thing.

Since you're already fetching your document, there is no need for you to issue an `findAndModify` operation, because when you call `.save()` method on `mongoose` document it issues an `update` operation, sending to MongoDB only updated fields:

```
collcetion[sindex].state = 'new state';
collcetion[hindex].state = 'new state';
collcetion.save(next);
// Mongoose sends update operation, setting only this two fields
```

Additionally, mongoose is using [versioning](http://aaronheckmann.blogspot.ru/2012/06/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning.html) to ensure that the order of documents in sub-documents array haven't changed, thus protecting you from updating wrong sub-document.